# Issue with JavaScript modal and input handling in HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-input, event-listener

I'm currently working on an HTML form that uses JavaScript to handle modals and input validation. The form is meant to capture a transfer value, and based on the value it should display modals for IA (Information Assurance) status and evidence received. However, I'm encountering an issue where the "Evidence Received" condition is not working as expected.

Here's the HTML structure and JavaScript code:

```js
const transferValueInput = document.getElementById('transferValue');
const submitButton = document.getElementById('submitButton');
const outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');
const modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
const modalButtonYes = document.getElementById('modalButtonYes');
const modalButtonNo = document.getElementById('modalButtonNo');
const evidenceModal = document.getElementById('evidenceModal');
const evidenceButtonYes = document.getElementById('evidenceButtonYes');
const evidenceButtonNo = document.getElementById('evidenceButtonNo');
const wiModal = document.getElementById('wiModal');
const wiInput = document.getElementById('wiInput');
const wiSaveButton = document.getElementById('wiSaveButton');

// Function to handle form submission
function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting
    const transferValue = parseFloat(transferValueInput.value);
    let outputText = `Transfer Value: ${transferValue}`;
    let iaStatus = modalButtonYes.getAttribute('data-selected') === 'true';
    const evidenceRequired = evidenceButtonNo.getAttribute('data-selected') === 'false';
    const evidenceReceived = evidenceButtonYes.getAttribute('data-selected') === 'true';

    if (!isNaN(transferValue) && transferValue >= 10000) {
        if (iaStatus) {
            outputText += " (IA status is authenticated).";
        } else if (evidenceRequired) {
            outputText += " (Evidence required as transfer value is above 10k).";
        } else if (evidenceReceived) {
            outputText += ` WI# Reference: ${wiInput.value}`;
        }
    }

    outputDiv.innerHTML = outputText;
    outputDiv.style.display = 'block'; // Show the output
}

// Function to hide the evidence received modal
function hideEvidenceModal() {
    evidenceModal.style display = 'none';
}

// Function to show the modal
function showModal() {
    modal.style.display = 'block';
}

// Function to hide the modal
function hideModal() {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
}

// Function to show the evidence received modal
function showEvidenceModal() {
    evidenceModal.style.display = 'block';
}

// Function to hide the evidence received modal
function hideEvidenceModal() {
    evidenceModal.style.display = 'none';
}

// Function to show the WI# modal
function showWiModal() {
    wiModal.style.display = 'block';
}

// Function to hide the WI# modal
function hideWiModal() {
    wiModal.style.display = 'none';
}

// Event listener for the "Yes" button in the IA status modal
modalButtonYes.addEventListener('click', () => {
    modalButtonYes.setAttribute('data-selected', 'true');
    hideModal();
});

modalButtonNo.addEventListener('click', () => {
    modalButtonYes.setAttribute('data-selected', 'false');
    hideModal();
    showEvidenceModal();
});

evidenceButtonYes.addEventListener('click', () => {
    evidenceButtonYes.setAttribute('data-selected', 'true');
    hideEvidenceModal();
    showWiModal();
});

// Event listener for the "No" button in the IA status modal
modalButtonNo.addEventListener('click', () => {
    modalButtonYes.setAttribute('data-selected', 'false');
    hideModal();
    showEvidenceModal();
});

// Event listeners for "No" button in evidenceModal and form submission
evidenceButtonNo.addEventListener('click', () => {
    evidenceButtonNo.setAttribute('data-selected', 'false');
    hideEvidenceModal();
});

// Event listener to show the IA status modal when transfer value is above 10k
transferValueInput.addEventListener('input', () => {
    const transferValue = parseFloat(transferValueInput.value);
    if (!isNaN(transferValue) && transferValue > 10000) {
        showModal();
    } else {
        hideModal();
    }
});

// Event listener to save the Wi refernce input from user
wiSaveButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    hideWiModal();
});

// Attach event listeners
submitButton.addEventListener('click', handleSubmit);
```

```css
/* Styles for the modal */
.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.modal-content {
    background-color: white;
    margin: 15% auto;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius: 5px;
}

/* Styles for the button */
.modal-button {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.modal-button-yes {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}

.modal-button-no {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}

/* Styles for the WI# modal */
.wi-modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.wi-modal-content {
    background-color: white;
    margin: 15% auto;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius: 5px;
}

/* Styles for the WI# input field */
#wiInput {
    width: 80%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

/* Styles for the "Save" button */
#wiSaveButton {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}

/* Styles for the output */
#output {
    display: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Input field for the transfer value -->
Transfer Value:

<br><br>

<!-- Submit button -->
<button id="submitButton">Submit</button>

<!-- Modal dialog for IA status -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h2>Is IA status Authenticated?</h2>
        <button class="modal-button modal-button-yes" id="modalButtonYes" data-     selected="false">Yes</button>
        <button class="modal-button modal-button-no" id="modalButtonNo" data-selected="false">No</button>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal dialog for Evidence received -->
<div id="evidenceModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h2>Is evidence received?</h2>
        <button class="modal-button modal-button-yes" id="evidenceButtonYes" data-      selected="false">Yes</button>
        <button class="modal-button modal-button-no" id="evidenceButtonNo" data-selected="false">No</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="wiModal" class="modal wi-modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h2>Enter WI# Reference Number:</h2>
        <input type="text" id="wiInput" placeholder="Enter WI# reference number">
        <button class="modal-button modal-button-yes" id="wiSaveButton">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Output div -->
<div id="output"></div>
```

The problem I'm facing is that when the "Evidence Received" button is clicked (with data-selected set to 'true'), the expected output should include "WI# Reference" along with the reference number entered in the modal. But this is not happening. I'm not getting the desired output.

I've checked the logic, and it seems fine to me, but I'm missing something. Can someone please help me identify the issue and get the "Evidence Received" condition to work correctly?

Comment: Is that your actual code, or just part of it? There is a missing opening `style` tag and no `head`/`body`.

Comment: what is `#transferValue` element ? where is the form ? [**you must provide an example reproducing this problem**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Its not an actual code its just a part of it. I have also not provided full form its just a part of it

Comment: there is no point in putting all your code. You need to make a meaningful and testable summary to highlight your problem. --> https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
Otherwise you have very little chance of getting help...

Comment: Why don't you simply use HTML5 modal dialogs and forms ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this section of code. You only ever receive evidence when it is required, but you never reach the test for `evidenceReceived` because the `evidenceRequired` test precedes it.

```
if (!isNaN(transferValue) && transferValue >= 10000) {
    if (iaStatus) {
        outputText += " (IA status is authenticated).";
    } else if (evidenceRequired) {
        outputText += " (Evidence required as transfer value is above 10k).";
    } else if (evidenceReceived) {
        outputText += ` WI# Reference: ${wiInput.value}`;
    }
}
```

Once solution would be to reverse the order of these tests. This is the solution I have included in the snippet below.

```
if (!isNaN(transferValue) && transferValue >= 10000) {
    if (iaStatus) {
        outputText += " (IA status is authenticated).";
    } else if (evidenceReceived) {
        outputText += ` WI# Reference: ${wiInput.value}`;
    } else if (evidenceRequired) {
        outputText += " (Evidence required as transfer value is above 10k).";
    }
}
```

```js
const transferValueInput = document.getElementById('transferValue');
const submitButton = document.getElementById('submitButton');
const outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');
const modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
const modalButtonYes = document.getElementById('modalButtonYes');
const modalButtonNo = document.getElementById('modalButtonNo');
const evidenceModal = document.getElementById('evidenceModal');
const evidenceButtonYes = document.getElementById('evidenceButtonYes');
const evidenceButtonNo = document.getElementById('evidenceButtonNo');
const wiModal = document.getElementById('wiModal');
const wiInput = document.getElementById('wiInput');
const wiSaveButton = document.getElementById('wiSaveButton');

// Function to handle form submission
function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting
    const transferValue = parseFloat(transferValueInput.value);
    let outputText = `Transfer Value: ${transferValue}`;
    let iaStatus = modalButtonYes.getAttribute('data-selected') === 'true';
    const evidenceRequired = evidenceButtonNo.getAttribute('data-selected') === 'false';
    const evidenceReceived = evidenceButtonYes.getAttribute('data-selected') === 'true';

    if (!isNaN(transferValue) && transferValue >= 10000) {
        if (iaStatus) {
            outputText += " (IA status is authenticated).";
        } else if (evidenceReceived) {
            outputText += ` WI# Reference: ${wiInput.value}`;
        } else if (evidenceRequired) {
            outputText += " (Evidence required as transfer value is above 10k).";
        }
    }

    outputDiv.innerHTML = outputText;
    outputDiv.style.display = 'block'; // Show the output
}

// Function to hide the evidence received modal
function hideEvidenceModal() {
    evidenceModal.style.display = 'none';
}

// Function to show the modal
function showModal() {
    modal.style.display = 'block';
}

// Function to hide the modal
function hideModal() {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
}

// Function to show the evidence received modal
function showEvidenceModal() {
    evidenceModal.style.display = 'block';
}

// Function to hide the evidence received modal
function hideEvidenceModal() {
    evidenceModal.style.display = 'none';
}

// Function to show the WI# modal
function showWiModal() {
    wiModal.style.display = 'block';
}

// Function to hide the WI# modal
function hideWiModal() {
    wiModal.style.display = 'none';
}

// Event listener for the "Yes" button in the IA status modal
modalButtonYes.addEventListener('click', () => {
    modalButtonYes.setAttribute('data-selected', 'true');
    hideModal();
});

modalButtonNo.addEventListener('click', () => {
    modalButtonYes.setAttribute('data-selected', 'false');
    hideModal();
    showEvidenceModal();
});

evidenceButtonYes.addEventListener('click', () => {
    evidenceButtonYes.setAttribute('data-selected', 'true');
    hideEvidenceModal();
    showWiModal();
});

// Event listener for the "No" button in the IA status modal
modalButtonNo.addEventListener('click', () => {
    modalButtonYes.setAttribute('data-selected', 'false');
    hideModal();
    showEvidenceModal();
});

// Event listeners for "No" button in evidenceModal and form submission
evidenceButtonNo.addEventListener('click', () => {
    evidenceButtonNo.setAttribute('data-selected', 'false');
    hideEvidenceModal();
});

// Event listener to show the IA status modal when transfer value is above 10k
transferValueInput.addEventListener('input', () => {
    const transferValue = parseFloat(transferValueInput.value);
    if (!isNaN(transferValue) && transferValue > 10000) {
        showModal();
    } else {
        hideModal();
    }
});

// Event listener to save the Wi refernce input from user
wiSaveButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    hideWiModal();
});

// Attach event listeners
submitButton.addEventListener('click', handleSubmit);
```

```css
/* Styles for the modal */
.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.modal-content {
    background-color: white;
    margin: 1% auto;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius: 5px;
}

/* Styles for the button */
.modal-button {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.modal-button-yes {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}

.modal-button-no {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}

/* Styles for the WI# modal */
.wi-modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.wi-modal-content {
    background-color: white;
    margin: 15% auto;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius: 5px;
}

/* Styles for the WI# input field */
#wiInput {
    width: 80%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

/* Styles for the "Save" button */
#wiSaveButton {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}

/* Styles for the output */
#output {
    display: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Input field for the transfer value -->
Enter a value greater than 10000 below<br><br>
Transfer Value:
<input id="transferValue" type="text">

<br><br>

<!-- Submit button -->
... then after dealing with the modals, press this button to see the output<br>
<button id="submitButton">Submit</button>

<!-- Modal dialog for IA status -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h2>Is IA status Authenticated?</h2>
        <button class="modal-button modal-button-yes" id="modalButtonYes" data-     selected="false">Yes</button>
        <button class="modal-button modal-button-no" id="modalButtonNo" data-selected="false">No</button>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal dialog for Evidence received -->
<div id="evidenceModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h2>Is evidence received?</h2>
        <button class="modal-button modal-button-yes" id="evidenceButtonYes" data-      selected="false">Yes</button>
        <button class="modal-button modal-button-no" id="evidenceButtonNo" data-selected="false">No</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="wiModal" class="modal wi-modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h2>Enter WI# Ref No:</h2>
        <input type="text" id="wiInput" placeholder="Enter WI# reference number">
        <button class="modal-button modal-button-yes" id="wiSaveButton">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Output div -->
<div id="output"></div>
```

Another possible solution would be add an extra condition to your second test, to prevent ias follows:

```
if (!isNaN(transferValue) && transferValue >= 10000) {
    if (iaStatus) {
        outputText += " (IA status is authenticated).";
    } else if (evidenceRequired && !evidenceReceived) {
        outputText += " (Evidence required as transfer value is above 10k).";
    } else if (evidenceReceived) {
        outputText += ` WI# Reference: ${wiInput.value}`;
    }
}
```

Comment: it didnt fix the issue

Comment: thanks for the code. I have use the code but the problem with code is when you use for first time its work fine but second time its give only WI refernce when i select no for is evidence required modal its dosent give the desired output